# Folder Actions Setup is a restricted service and folder actions are not working

Tags: finder, monterey, folder-action

On a fresh Monterey install, when right-clicking on a folder and selecting `Folder Actions Setup...`, I get the following warning:

[image]

I click on `Run Service`, I can create my action via Automator etc.
The problem is that the action never triggers and each time I'm clicking on the `Folder Actions Setup...` I still get the same warning, wondering if the service is actually running, which would explain why the actions are not triggered.

This may be linked to a file permission issue or a Privacy setting issue, one service not having Full Access to the hard drive.

Is there at least a log somewhere telling me if it tried or not to run the action? Didn't find anything useful in the Console. Action is of course running fine in Automator.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and this is how I fixed it:

1. Open the script through the **Folder Actions Setup** option.
2. Click **Edit** on the script that isn't working
3. In Automator, re-compile the script and check if all your file paths are still correct. (Turns out that some volumes I was interacting with had different names in Monterey.)
4. **Save** the script in Automator

After that, it worked like it used to. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @phigliani thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't fix my issue. It's a new script, not an old one that would have been imported from another system or OS version.

Comment: For me, disabling and *re-enabling* the folder actions in the "Service" dropdown settings popup fixed this.